# Converting Web Browser Automation to XmlHTTP Request

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, automation, xmlhttprequest

I have created a macro which scrapes relevant information from `Brief profiles (BP)` that can be searched for at: https://echa.europa.eu/information-on-chemicals

This works using an XMLHTTP request to the URL of the `Brief Profile` and works fine.

I now wish to create a macro which searches the same website to find the URL(href) of the brief profile.

As a beginner to VBA I have successfully achieved this using a browser but I wish to convert this to XML HTTP request to improve efficiency.

**Using IE Browser Automation:**

```
Sub Gethref()

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLButtom As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

Dim HTMLhref As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

'Go to Website
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://echa.europa.eu/information-on-chemicals"

'Check Website is ready for search and set HTMLDoc to IE.Document for elements
Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

Set HTMLDoc = IE.document

'Set value of Searchbox to keyword
Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_sskeywordKey")
HTMLInput.Value = "Potassium mercaptoacetate"

'Search for Result
Set HTMLButton = HTMLDoc.getElementById("_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_searchButton")
HTMLButton.Click

'Check page has loaded
Do While IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE or IE.Busy
Loop
Set HTMLDoc = IE.document

'Find Desired href
Set HTMLhref = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("briefProfileLink")(0)
Debug.Print HTMLhref.getAttribute("href")

End Sub
```

This should print the href for `Potassium mercaptoacetate` as `https://echa.europa.eu/brief-profile/-/briefprofile/100.000.602`

I have started attempted to convert as much as I can using XML HTTP but Im running into issues which I dont quite understand

**Using XML HTTP Request (Not working)**

```
Sub Gethref()

    Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLButtom As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

Dim HTMLhref As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

'Go to Website
    XMLPage.Open "GET", "https://echa.europa.eu/information-on-chemicals", False
    XMLPage.send
    
'Set value of Searchbox to keyword
    Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_sskeywordKey")
    HTMLInput.Value

'Search for Result
    Set HTMLButton = HTMLDoc.getElementById("_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_searchButton")
    HTMLButton.Click

'Check page has loaded
HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = IE.document.responseText

'Find Desired href
    Set HTMLhref = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("briefProfileLink")(0)
    Debug.Print HTMLhref.getAttribute("href")

End Sub
```

I will update as I make progress with this but if anyone can offer help it will be great.

Comment: Code leads to results for Acetone with multiple brief profilelinks.

Comment: @QHarr When I tested it in the browser Class name BriefProfileLink(0) only returned the first Profile link?

Comment: @QHarr Yeah Just ran it again and `https://echa.europa.eu/brief-profile/-/briefprofile/100.047.293` is returned as the only result.

Comment: I mean entering the search term Acetone doesn't lead to Potassium mercaptoacetate does it? Disclaimer: I was following manually rather than running the code

Comment: @QHarr Ah yes sorry about that I have just updated the code to search for Potassium mercaptoacetate to be consistent however it shouldn't really matter as I am just trying to return whatever the first Brief Profile Link is for any searched chemical, whether this be acetone, Potassium mercaptoacetate etc. But yes you're right these will have different Profile links that will be returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, this should do it. Turn out that you need to issue post http requests with appropriate parameters to get required response containing desired links.

```
Public Sub GetContent()
    Const Url = "https://echa.europa.eu/search-for-chemicals?p_auth=5ayUnMyz&p_p_id=disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_col_id=_118_INSTANCE_UFgbrDo05Elj__column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_javax.portlet.action=doSearchAction&_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_backURL=https%3A%2F%2Fecha.europa.eu%2Finformation-on-chemicals%3Fp_p_id%3Ddisssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dnormal%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26p_p_col_id%3D_118_INSTANCE_UFgbrDo05Elj__column-1%26p_p_col_count%3D1%26_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_sessionCriteriaId%3D"
    Dim oHttp As Object, oHtml As HTMLDocument, MyDict As Object, I&, R&
    Dim DictKey As Variant, payload$, searchKeyword$, Ws As Worksheet
    
    Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set MyDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    searchKeyword = "Acetone"
    
    MyDict("_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_formDate") = "1621017052777" 'timestamp
    MyDict("_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_searchOccurred") = "true"
    MyDict("_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_sskeywordKey") = searchKeyword
    MyDict("_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_disclaimer") = "true"
    MyDict("_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_disclaimerCheckbox") = "on"

    payload = ""
    For Each DictKey In MyDict
        payload = IIf(Len(DictKey) = 0, WorksheetFunction.encodeURL(DictKey) & "=" & WorksheetFunction.encodeURL(MyDict(DictKey)), _
        payload & "&" & WorksheetFunction.encodeURL(DictKey) & "=" & WorksheetFunction.encodeURL(MyDict(DictKey)))
    Next DictKey
    
    With oHttp
        .Open "POST", Url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .send (payload)
        oHtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    With oHtml.querySelectorAll("table.table > tbody > tr > td > a.substanceNameLink")
        For I = 0 To .Length - 1
            R = R + 1: Ws.Cells(R, 1) = .item(I).getAttribute("href")
        Next I
    End With
End Sub
```

If you are interested in the first link only, try the following instead of the last with block:

```
MsgBox oHtml.querySelector("table.table > tbody > tr > td > a.substanceNameLink").getAttribute("href")
```

Or you can directly copy those parameters from dev tool and use them:

```
Public Sub GetContent()
    Const Url = "https://echa.europa.eu/search-for-chemicals?"
    Dim oHttp As Object, oHtml As HTMLDocument
    Dim payload$, Ws As Worksheet, urlSuffix$
    
    Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    urlSuffix = "p_auth=69hDou3E&p_p_id=disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_col_id=" & _
                "_118_INSTANCE_UFgbrDo05Elj__column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_javax.portlet.action=" & _
                "doSearchAction&_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_backURL=https%3A%2F%2Fecha.europa.eu%2Finformation-on-chemicals" & _
                "%3Fp_p_id%3Ddisssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dnormal%26p_p_mode%3Dview" & _
                "%26p_p_col_id%3D_118_INSTANCE_UFgbrDo05Elj__column-1%26p_p_col_count%3D1%26_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_sessionCriteriaId%3D"

    payload = "_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_formDate=1621042609544&_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_searchOccurred=" & _
              "true&_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_sskeywordKey=Acetone&_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_disclaimer" & _
              "=true&_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_disclaimerCheckbox=on"
    
    With oHttp
        .Open "POST", Url & urlSuffix, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .send (payload)
        oHtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    Debug.Print oHtml.querySelector("table.table > tbody > tr > td > a.substanceNameLink").getAttribute("href")
End Sub
```

Comment: Out of interest why are all of the MyDict elements Necessary? Also I noticed the URL is much longer and wondered why do you do this? Thanks again though, realy appreciated.

Comment: Nope, not at all. You can directly copy the relevant portion from dev tool and store in payload before using it.

Comment: Hi again, Ive just been going through this code one more and was hoping you could explain why the URL used is much longer, or in your second example requires the suffix? using just `https://echa.europa.eu/search-for-chemicals` and the code fails. However if I wish to to apply what Ive learnt here to a different website, or indeed if the website were to change I dont know where I would get the extensive url from?

Comment: I think [this image](https://imgur.com/23dGsLf) explains everything you wanted to know @Nick.

Comment: Hey again, I'm currently looking into Url parameters and think this post holds the key to my question.  Ive taken a look at that image you shared which is really useful but I'm still confused as to where the const URL `https://echa.europa.eu/search-for-chemicals?p_auth=5ayUnMyz&p_p_id=disssimpl...` comes from. I appreciate the values wont be identical per session but if you could let me know where you found this what would be really useful