# Getting href from web page in power query for excel

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, powerquery

I am attempting to collect href data in power query for excel for any results found on https://echa.europa.eu/ when searching for 'Acetone'.

Current M Code:

```
let
    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(
        
        "https://echa.europa.eu/search-for-chemicals?" & 

        //Parameters
        "p_auth=69hDou3E&p_p_id=disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_col_id=" &
        "_118_INSTANCE_UFgbrDo05Elj__column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_javax.portlet.action=" &
        "doSearchAction&_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_backURL=https%3A%2F%2Fecha.europa.eu%2Finformation-on-chemicals" &
        "%3Fp_p_id%3Ddisssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dnormal%26p_p_mode%3Dview" &
        "%26p_p_col_id%3D_118_INSTANCE_UFgbrDo05Elj__column-1%26p_p_col_count%3D1%26_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_sessionCriteriaId%3D" &
        
        
        "_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_formDate=1621042609544&_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_searchOccurred=" &
        "true&_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_sskeywordKey=Acetone&_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_disclaimer" &
        "=true&_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_disclaimerCheckbox=on")),
    
    
    Data = Source{0}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data,{{"Name", type text}, {"EC / List no.", type text}, {"CAS no.", type text}, {"BP", type text}, {"OBL", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

The parameters are form a previous [VBA Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67537598/converting-web-browser-automation-to-xmlhttp-request):

This returns:
[image]

As you can see the BP is returned just saying Open Brief Profile instead of the Href for each chemical.

Desired result for acetone in BP column:
[image]

I know this can be done using table from examples using Power BI but since I manipulate the data in excel it's more useful to pull it straight from here.

I have explored this previously with no success however https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/web-connector-and-getting-HREF-value/m-p/422068 gives me hope that it could be done? I have tried this though and run into issues.

If anyone could advise whether this could be done it would be appreciated. the final result is that column BP (not bothered about OBL) containsa href for each result in the table.

Comment: Doesnt seem like it.  Web.Page(Web.Contents()) is omitting the results, Lines.FromBinary(Web.Contents()) does not evaluate to include them

Comment: Ill leave posted for a while to see if anyone can think of a workaround. I doubt it but worth a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents("https://echa.europa.eu/search-for-chemicals?p_p_id=disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet&p_p_lifecycle=2&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_resource_id=exportResults&p_p_cacheability=cacheLevelPage&_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_sessionCriteriaId=dissSimpleSearchSessionParam101401654440118533&_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_formDate=1654440118558&_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_sskeywordKey=Acetone&_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_orderByCol=relevance&_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_orderByType=asc&_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_exportType=xls"))[Data]{0}
    
    
    
in
    Source
```