# Is it possible to parameterise a url such that url title display as href - PQ

Tags: html, powerquery, url-parameters, web-inspector

Not sure if this is possible but I'm attempting to extract href link in Power query for Excel but have run into an issue that the link text is returned instead of the href. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72461702/getting-href-from-web-page-in-power-query-for-excel) for more info.

Struggling to find a solution but as a last-ditch attempt im wondering if its possible to parameterise a URL such that the page displays the URL in full instead of a link i.e when I hover over `BP` in the images below:

From this:
[image]

To this:
[image]

As I say im not sure if this is doable but may solve the problem Im having extracting all of the Hrefs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken a look and I really think this is not possible with PQ. Have you considered scraping the site with something like Power Automate? e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DgBZiBIgh3w

**EDIT 1:**
Try this:

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents("https://echa.europa.eu/search-for-chemicals?p_p_id=disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet&p_p_lifecycle=2&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_resource_id=exportResults&p_p_cacheability=cacheLevelPage&_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_sessionCriteriaId=dissSimpleSearchSessionParam101401654440118533&_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_formDate=1654440118558&_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_sskeywordKey=Acetone&_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_orderByCol=relevance&_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_orderByType=asc&_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_exportType=xls"))[Data]{0}
    
    
    
in
    Source
```

**EDIT 2:**

In FireFox, open developer tools with F12. Go to the Network tab in the dev tools. Click the export button on the web page for CSV or XLS. A new entry will appear in the network tab. Highlight it and then look at the request parameters that were sent.

[image]

Comment: Yes, perhaps this isn't the best way. One final thing I want to explore is the parameter `_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_exportData('xls');` to export the searched results as XLS, CSV OR XML. But I think you are right. Hopefully will install power automate tomorrow and explore this.

Comment: I didn't spot the export options. I have updated my answer - see what you think.

Comment: Thats really great, do you know how I can modify it to just return the top result? i.e. `_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_delta=1` I intend to create a function that look up the relevant URLs for a given chemical name. putting in this parameter doesn't change the number returned. I appreciate I can filter but just want to make the source data as clean as I can]

Comment: That parameter doesn't seem to do anything when I add it to the query string so afraid not. You can write some M in your function to just return the first result though.

Comment: Sure, I just wonder how you got _disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_exportType=xls. When I tried this initially the same results just returned as previous. I suspect that it is possible to get delta = 1 to return its just my misunderstanding. Apprecaite your help though!

Comment: I found it by looking at the request that was being posted in the network tab of the browser to see what was being passed to the server. I then copied everything into the query I wrote. Don't forget to mark this as solved if you're happy with the answer.

Comment: Sorry to keep asking but thats what I attempted at first but couldn't get a request for the export. Do you mind if I ask what steps you took to get the parameter 'p_p_resource_id=exportResults`

Comment: I'll update the answer with the steps.

Comment: Thank you, its not always obvious just reading the answer!

Comment: Done. Don't forget to mark as solved once you're happy with the answer. You should be able to write an M function from this point on but post another question if you still need help.

Comment: Ahh okay I see, it downloads a set amount regardless of this parameter. Thank you! learnt something new