# POST request with power query not returning desired result

Tags: excel, web-scraping, powerbi, powerquery, xls

Following on form a successfully answered post here: [Is it possible to parameterise a url such that url title display as href - PQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72507823/is-it-possible-to-parameterise-a-url-such-that-url-title-display-as-href-pq)

I am trying to do the same with a different area of the same website (provides two different types of useful links: Factsheet Url and Substance information Page) create a function that can Download the Xlxs data from the website for searched chemicals through power query.

So far however the excel file downloaded doesnt appear to contain the right data and im not sure what im doing wrong.

Steps takemn:

1. Search on https://echa.europa.eu/information-on-chemicals/registered-substances For Substance name: Acetone and CAS number:67-64-1
2. Click on export button once searched for and then with developer tools open clicked on the XLS button to identify from network the POST reuqest and parameters which can be seen in the M Code:

[image]

**Request URL:**

```
https://echa.europa.eu/information-on-chemicals/registered-substances?p_p_id=dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet&p_p_lifecycle=2&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_resource_id=exportResults&p_p_cacheability=cacheLevelPage&_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_sessionCriteriaId=dissRegSubsSessionParam101401655391028695
```

**Form Data:**

```
_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_formDate=1655391028770&disreg_substanceMasterSearchPerformed=false&substanceId=&disreg_substanceDetailsSearchPerformed=false&businessIdentifier=&disreg_ec-number=&disreg_cas-number=67-64-1&disreg_name=Acetone&disreg_registrationNumber=&disreg_registrant=&disreg_registrantAddress=&disreg_totalTonnageBandMin=null&disreg_totalTonnageBandMax=1000000000&disreg_lastUpdateMinDate=&disreg_lastUpdateMaxDate=&disreg_registrantLastUpdateYear=null&disreg_country=&disreg_pbtAssessmentOutcome=null&disreg_csaPerformed=&disreg_registrationType=&disreg_registrationStatus=&disreg_submissionType=&disreg_firstPublishedMinDate=&disreg_firstPublishedMaxDate=&disreg_tonnageBandType=ALL&disreg_usesOperator=AND&_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_disreg_useCategories%5B%5D=useType1&_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_disreg_useCategories%5B%5D=useType2&_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_disreg_useCategories%5B%5D=useType3&_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_disreg_useCategories%5B%5D=useType4&_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_disreg_useCategories%5B%5D=useType5&disreg_highlightedname=&disreg_highlightedecnumber=&disreg_highlightedcasnumber=&disreg_orderByCol=relevance&disreg_orderByType=asc&_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_disreg_exportType=xls&_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_disreg_exportTab=ALL+SUBSTANCES
```

When throwing this into M Code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents("https://echa.europa.eu/information-on-chemicals/registered-substances?"&
    
    //URL Request
    "p_p_id=dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet&p_p_lifecycle=2&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_resource_id=exportResults&p_p_cacheability=cacheLevelPage&_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_sessionCriteriaId=dissRegSubsSessionParam101401655391028695"&

    //Form Data
    "_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_formDate=1655391028770&disreg_substanceMasterSearchPerformed=false&substanceId=&disreg_substanceDetailsSearchPerformed=false&businessIdentifier=&disreg_ec-number=&disreg_cas-number=67-64-1&disreg_name=Acetone&disreg_registrationNumber=&disreg_registrant=&disreg_registrantAddress=&disreg_totalTonnageBandMin=null&disreg_totalTonnageBandMax=1000000000&disreg_lastUpdateMinDate=&disreg_lastUpdateMaxDate=&disreg_registrantLastUpdateYear=null&disreg_country=&disreg_pbtAssessmentOutcome=null&disreg_csaPerformed=&disreg_registrationType=&disreg_registrationStatus=&disreg_submissionType=&disreg_firstPublishedMinDate=&disreg_firstPublishedMaxDate=&disreg_tonnageBandType=ALL&disreg_usesOperator=AND&_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_disreg_useCategories%5B%5D=useType1&_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_disreg_useCategories%5B%5D=useType2&_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_disreg_useCategories%5B%5D=useType3&_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_disreg_useCategories%5B%5D=useType4&_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_disreg_useCategories%5B%5D=useType5&disreg_highlightedname=&disreg_highlightedecnumber=&disreg_highlightedcasnumber=&disreg_orderByCol=relevance&disreg_orderByType=asc&_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_disreg_exportType=xls&_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_disreg_exportTab=ALL+SUBSTANCES"

))[Data]{0}
    
    
    
in
    Source
```

Unfortunately this just returns:

[image]

Which when compared to the opening the actual Xls file:

[image]

So im confident this can be done but clearly something isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine but there is definitely something wrong. It is either a PQ bug or the server is responding with a malformed response of some kind. If I copy and paste the text from Web.Content below into a browser window, it opens a CSV for me. However, in PQ, only the first few lines are read for some reason and the file is truncated. I'll be interested to see if anyone else has encountered this before.

```
let
    Source =   Web.Contents("https://echa.europa.eu/information-on-chemicals/registered-substances?p_p_id=dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet&p_p_lifecycle=2&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_resource_id=exportResults&p_p_cacheability=cacheLevelPage&_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_sessionCriteriaId=dissRegSubsSessionParam101401655398538618&POSThttps://echa.europa.eu/information-on-chemicals/registered-substances?p_p_id=dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet&p_p_lifecycle=2&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_resource_id=exportResults&p_p_cacheability=cacheLevelPage&_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_sessionCriteriaId=dissRegSubsSessionParam101401655398538618[HTTP/1.1%20200%20200%20568ms]1_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_formDate=1655398538719&disreg_substanceMasterSearchPerformed=false&substanceId=&disreg_substanceDetailsSearchPerformed=false&businessIdentifier=&disreg_ec-number=&disreg_cas-number=&disreg_name=Acetone&disreg_registrationNumber=&disreg_registrant=&disreg_registrantAddress=&disreg_totalTonnageBandMin=null&disreg_totalTonnageBandMax=1000000000&disreg_lastUpdateMinDate=&disreg_lastUpdateMaxDate=&disreg_registrantLastUpdateYear=null&disreg_country=&disreg_pbtAssessmentOutcome=null&disreg_csaPerformed=&disreg_registrationType=&disreg_registrationStatus=&disreg_submissionType=&disreg_firstPublishedMinDate=&disreg_firstPublishedMaxDate=&disreg_tonnageBandType=ALL&disreg_usesOperator=AND&_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_disreg_useCategories%5B%5D=useType1&_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_disreg_useCategories%5B%5D=useType2&_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_disreg_useCategories%5B%5D=useType3&_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_disreg_useCategories%5B%5D=useType4&_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_disreg_useCategories%5B%5D=useType5&disreg_highlightedname=&disreg_highlightedecnumber=&disreg_highlightedcasnumber=&disreg_orderByCol=relevance&disreg_orderByType=asc&_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_disreg_exportType=csv&_dissregisteredsubstances_WAR_dissregsubsportlet_disreg_exportTab=ALL+SUBSTANCES"),

    #"Imported Text" = Table.FromColumns({Lines.FromBinary(Source)})
in
    #"Imported Text"
```

Comment: I get identical results with direct browser returning a CSV or with Davids code, starting with Registered Substances
 and ending with "registrantLastUpdateYear ""null"""

Comment: Have you ever seen anything like this before @horseyride? You can switch the csv for xls and the same thing happens. It seems like the file is being truncated by Web.Contents.

Comment: There is something occasionally wrong with the PQ scraper where where Web.Contents doesnt work correctly on its own or via Web.Page(Web.Contents()) or Lines.FromBinary(Web.Contents())   However in this case, I don't see an issue

Comment: @horseyride any thoughts whats going on to cause this?